# Getting all indices of elements matching criteria in F#

Tags: collections, f#

Let's make a list:

```
let l = [ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5 ]
```

how do I get a list of indices for elements matching a predicate?

I can do:

```
l |> List.FindIndex (fun x -> x >=2 && x <= 4)
```

but it will return me a single index, for the first matching case.
What I'm looking for is a function that returns: [ 1; 2; 3 ], for this example, or [] if nothing matches

I could feed the list tail recursively and achieve that, but it's convoluted and messy. I could iterate through the list and add indices to a collection, but it's also cumbersome.

Is there anything existing in a collection library? I looked to a `'T list -> int list` signature but can't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a built in function on the List module for this, but it easy enough to use the other functions to do it.

```ml
let l = [ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5 ]

let idxs = 
    l
    |> List.indexed
    |> List.filter (fun (_, x) -> x >= 2 && x <= 4)
    |> List.map fst
```

If you want your own `findIndicies` function like `Data.List` in Haskell you can do this:

```
module List =
    let findIndicies filter xs =
        xs
        |> List.indexed
        |> List.filter (snd >> filter)
        |> List.map fst

l |> List.findIndicies (fun x -> x >= 2 && x <= 4)
```

Comment: Some tips, simplification: Your `List.mapi` line can be shortened to just `List.indexed`. Instead of `List.filter`, you can use `List.choose` (this allows you to change the filtered items), and the last line can then be dropped.

Comment: @Abel I didn't know about `indexed` - thanks, added it. 
I'm never sure on `choose`. Would that be: `(fun (idx, x) -> if filter x then Some idx else None)`?

Comment: @DaveShow, yes, that's a perfectly fine way of doing it (except, it's `fun idx x -> ...`). And if you want `filter` to be expanded to operate on both `idx` and `x`, you can use `List.choose filter`, and the filter function becomes `fun i x -> if x >= 2 && x <= 4 then Some i else None`.

Comment: That way, the caller has more freedom, and you essentially coded a `List.choosei` function.